# Shell script to read value pairs from txt file

Tags: arrays, shell

I have a set of value pairs in a text file and need to read them in two different arrays. The values in the file are stored in the following manner

```
100=5
300=10
19=30
```

I need to read 100, 300, 19 in a separate array and 5,10 and 30 in a different array. so far I'm able to read the values of 5,10 and 30, but how do I read the other values?
below is the code i have to read the assigned values.

```
while read -r line; do declare  $line; done <file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) does not specify an array datatype (the tags only mention "shell"), so you cannot "read them in two different arrays" unless you're willing to use a shell which supports such a datatype.

This should work in Bash (untested):

```
keys=()
values=()
while IFS='=' read -r key value
do
    keys+=("$key")
    values+=("$value")
done < key_value_pairs.txt
```

References:

- [IFS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS)
- [Word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)
- [Arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)

Comment: Can you expound on the answer i dont get you

Comment: Which part of it needs explaining?

Comment: the third line `IFS='=' read -r key value` what is key and value here and where do i give the file name to read from?

Comment: Please bare with me I'm completely new to scripting

Comment: `key` and `value` are the variable names which are populated with the strings before and after the equals sign, respectively.